# Orbits of ${S_n}$ in ${J \times J}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that for ${S_n}$, there are exactly two orbits in ${J \times J}$, where $J = {1,2,....n}$.

My proof so far proceeds as follows:

Take ${(x,y) , (a,b)}$ in $J \times J$. Take s in ${S_n}$, where s sends (x,y) to (a,b), where $a \neq b$, $x \neq a$, and $y \neq b$. Suppose $x \neq y$. Therefore, s(x,y) can be equal to either (x,b), (x,y), (a,y), (a,b). Note that (x,y) can be sent to any other distinct integers (a,b).

Now suppose $x = y$. It is clear to see that x and y are going to both be mapped to the same integer under s.

Therefore there are two orbits: where the two integers are the same, and where the two integers are different.

Does this make sense...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, assuming that $n \ge 2$.

Fix a pair $(x, y) \in J \times J$.

If $x \ne y$, then for any $(a, b) \in J \times J$ with $a \ne b$, there exists a permutation $s \in S_n$ such that
$$
s(x) = a \qquad \text{and} \qquad s(y) = b.
$$
(Notice, that it's not necessary for $x \ne a$ nor $y \ne b$.)  Therefore, the orbit of $(x, y)$ is 
$$
\{ (a, b) \in J \times J \mid a \ne b \}.
$$

If $x = y$, then for any $a \in J$, there exists $s \in S_n$ such that $s(x) = a$.  Therefore, the orbit of $(x, x)$ is
$$
\{ (a, a) \mid a \in J \}.
$$